# AngularJS $http: send message ignoring fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given the following object:

```
var msg = {x: 1, y: 2, z: 3};
```

I need to send it via $http, however **ignoring** field 'y'. For example:

```
msg = IgnoreFields ( msg, 'y' );  // <-- example of what I'm looking for
$http.post('/someUrl', msg );
```

should send the message:

```
msg = { x: 1, z: 3}
```

Is there a way to do this in Angular and/or JS or I have to do it manually? I'm dealing with large objects.

**EDIT**

The object could have nested objects and arrays, and fields on those nested elements may need to be deleted as well. The calling function should disregard where the field is located.

Comment: do you still need your object after ? you could just delete the property: `delete msg.y`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function IgnoreFields(obj, keyName) {
  obj = angular.copy(obj);

  for (key in obj) {
    if (key == keyName) {
      delete obj[key];
    }
    else if (typeof obj == 'object') {
      obj[key] = IgnoreFields(obj[key], keyName);
    }
 }

 return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create the exact method you want:

```
function IgnoreFields(obj, field) {
    var copyObj = angular.copy(obj);
    if (copyObj.hasOwnProperty(field)) delete copyObj[field];

    return copyObj;
}
```

Comment: @pgschr -- the calling function can't "disregard" where the field is located. You'll need a much more advanced function then to find out what to delete. Why not just have your server handle disregarding?